# Using qdatetime- cannot write image to path

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

My target is to save an image (opencv 2.4.13) and include the current date-time in the image's name (something like: current-datetime.jpg). I have tried below code-

```
string d_t = 
QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate).toLocal8Bit().constData();
string output_file = 
"F:\\WorkSpace\\QtPractice\\resource\\face_db\\"+d_t+".jpg";
cv::imwrite(output_file, image);
cout << output_file << endl; //  to check the file location
```

But I get nothing in my targeted location.

When I try below code to check if it's working correctly to save the image-

```
string d_t = to_string(3.1415926)
string output_file = "F:\\WorkSpace\\QtPractice\\resource\\face_db\\"+d_t+".jpg";
cv::imwrite(output_file, image);
cout << output_file << endl;
```

And it works fine. So, I think I have done something wrong to convert the string as the second code works correctly. Can someone please help me to write the image with the current date-time and what have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate).toStdString();`

Comment: @Miki , tried this too. Didn't work. Still not getting the image to be saved.

Comment: IsoDate has colons ":" which are not valid for a path.. Use another date format

Comment: @miki, now I don't understand which format can i use (basically I need the IsoDate format with the colons). According to this documentation, the other formats either has colons ':' or spaces. Can you please suggest me how can I get this corrected?
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Miki for the guidance. To answer this myself, I have converted the date-time format to a customized format and thus this is resolved. Below is the complete code-

```
QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();
string d_t = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss").toStdString();
string output_file = "F:\\WorkSpace\\QtPractice\\resource\\face_db\\"+d_t+".jpg";
cv::imwrite(output_file, image);
```